# Have a query that extracts json and uses that data to join on another table. Query works but when I add another column to it, it returns way more rows

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-json

I have a query that extracts json and uses that data to join onto another table. The query works great but when I add another column to it(stored_events.created_at), it returns way more rows. About 1,000 more rows. I want the query to work, where it does not add to the original amount of rows, as I think the original amount of rows is correct.

My two tables look like the below:

Leads:

```
id           first_name  last_name  email                mobile_phone phone club_id   ip_address                            lead_type created_at
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|d099661f-e81b-40f4-b72d|Jasmine    |Kramph   |kroese@test.com              |9258859221  |NULL  |7701   |2602:555:c700:6bf0:58d0:28fb:1e8a:48d8|web-sales|2023-04-26 03:03:50|
|b051626d-6272-41ce-8704|William    |Smith    |Warsame.O.Guled@test.com     |6125553704  |NULL  |7701   |2602:447:c680:f810:c1d0:5555:9d08:2ca9|web-sales|2023-04-26 02:44:02|
|6e013396-2198-4f27-bd68|Royal      |DeSales  |royalakeem21@test.com        |4146301591  |NULL  |7773   |75.86.55.206                          |web-sales|2023-04-26 01:47:31|
|60aded8e-715d-454a-ac28|Oscar      |Rose     |Austin222mtz@test.com        |4143694669  |NULL  |7776   |98.555.131.10                         |web-sales|2023-04-26 01:20:41|
|cc665804-4efb-48c1-bea5|Angelique  |Lopez    |angelique.gonzales31@test.com|4146984637  |NULL  |7773   |65.55.227.151                         |web-sales|2023-04-26 01:06:15|
|6cd79389-c582-4254-b43c|jasmina    |taylor   |jasminachoeunmunesy@test.com |4145070451  |NULL  |7776   |2600:5555:b168:63a8:41cd:2941:5555:aff|web-sales|2023-04-26 00:46:50|
|6eeb66f1-ef3a-4e52-916d|Noe        |Smith    |noesanchez040404@gtest.com   |4146555330  |NULL  |7776   |98.103.555.10.                        |web-sales|2023-04-26 00:31:10|
|4811a04d-0f28-413e-b707|Tammy      |Ward     |lrobinso51@gtest.com         |2625662531  |NULL  |7771   |2603:555:dd00:6d0d:44d0:9643:8ad4:8c40|web-sales|2023-04-26 00:16:50|
|0716f87d-4301-4b0c-ab5b|Calen      |Warner   |kahncaleb@test.com           |5556567391  |NULL  |7719   |96.93.555.26                          |web-sales|2023-04-26 00:03:22|
|922d2086-8947-4fd3-9af7|Derrick B. |West     |dbwright054@test.com         |4145553920  |NULL  |7776   |2600:5555:5fea:1a00:bbc7:db43:c9e3:9b4|web-sales|2023-04-25 23:44:18|
|d68066f0-74ce-412f-bb9a|Maddy      |White    |mohaugerud32@test.com        |5553386395  |NULL  |7719    |2607:5555:fa26:5730:add:707b:2837:19e|web-sales|2023-04-25 23:18:58|
```

stored_events:

```
    id       aggregate_uuid                      av event_class                                         event_properties                                                                                                          created_at
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |200089|f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:38|
    |200090|f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"3758\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_appleton_addressable_geo_fencing\"}, \"token\": \"f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:38|
    |200091|f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:08:38\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"216.93.13.555\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251\", \"campaign\": \"display_appleton_addressable_geo_fencing\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"programmatic\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"3758\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_appleton_addressable_geo_fencing\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"f0702918-fecd-46c7-b266-52dc2e52c251\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:38|
    |200086|a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:35|
    |200087|a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7758\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_hales_corners_addressable_geo_fencing\"}, \"token\": \"a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:35|
    |200088|a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:08:35\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"216.93.14.555\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40\", \"campaign\": \"display_hales_corners_addressable_geo_fencing\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"programmatic\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7758\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_hales_corners_addressable_geo_fencing\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"a7c46a0e-3232-4a73-a83f-2b7066da5e40\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:35|
    |200083|00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:31|
    |200084|00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7719\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_coon_rapids_geo_fencing\"}, \"token\": \"00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:31|
    |200085|00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:08:31\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"168.555.174.49\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae\", \"campaign\": \"display_coon_rapids_geo_fencing\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"programmatic\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7719\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_coon_rapids_geo_fencing\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"00d633ed-5e42-4153-a97e-f011669bc4ae\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:31|
    |200080|7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:15|
    |200081|7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7701\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_roseville_addressable_geo_fencing\"}, \"token\": \"7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:15|
    |200082|7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:08:15\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"45.555.96.7\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63\", \"campaign\": \"display_roseville_addressable_geo_fencing\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"programmatic\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7701\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_roseville_addressable_geo_fencing\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"7095fd95-d714-4b46-be02-96937b0a9b63\"}|2023-04-26 04:08:15|
    |200077|e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192\"}|2023-04-26 04:06:58|
    |200078|e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"SPRING23\", \"clubID\": \"7776\", \"fbclid\": \"IwAR0VEJMJanKuZciQm641EjglKQLDOIPU8TVQuPRBXlj1zD2yldLc2Q8LAXk_aem_AZtjvBmz2n5h5TCEhIIscKbR1bNKR2R6giZNj-kEleUTJhiSR0pUfd6D3XzF3A6xOM90k_HBc_b9DzvzlOrpp1MxCCQO4YcFuqzo3dTBqDyu6HzvtUVVoRupScyRqFOr7uZi3Glf_yGD8HYIy6DadMhG\", \"hsa_ad\": \"23853502958920441\", \"hsa_acc\": \"2256012071346889\", \"hsa_cam\": \"23853324597680441\", \"hsa_grp\": \"23853324597700441\", \"hsa_net\": \"facebook\", \"hsa_src\": \"fb\", \"hsa_ver\": \"3\", \"utm_term\": \"Spring23_p1_c1_h1\", \"utm_medium\": \"paid_social\", \"utm_source\": \"facebook\", \"utm_content\": \"greenfield_pin_drop\", \"utm_campaign\": \"greenfield_link_click_campaign\"}, \"token\": \"e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192\"}|2023-04-26 04:06:58|
    |200079|e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:06:58\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"2600:1702:555:fe10:58c1:6791:430e:a29c\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192\", \"campaign\": \"greenfield_link_click_campaign\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"facebook\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"SPRING23\", \"clubID\": \"7776\", \"fbclid\": \"IwAR0VEJMJanKuZciQm641EjglKQLDOIPU8TVQuPRBXlj1zD2yldLc2Q8LAXk_aem_AZtjvBmz2n5h5TCEhIIscKbR1bNKR2R6giZNj-kEleUTJhiSR0pUfd6D3XzF3A6xOM90k_HBc_b9DzvzlOrpp1MxCCQO4YcFuqzo3dTBqDyu6HzvtUVVoRupScyRqFOr7uZi3Glf_yGD8HYIy6DadMhG\", \"hsa_ad\": \"23853502958920441\", \"hsa_acc\": \"2256012071346889\", \"hsa_cam\": \"23853324597680441\", \"hsa_grp\": \"23853324597700441\", \"hsa_net\": \"facebook\", \"hsa_src\": \"fb\", \"hsa_ver\": \"3\", \"utm_term\": \"Spring23_p1_c1_h1\", \"utm_medium\": \"paid_social\", \"utm_source\": \"facebook\", \"utm_content\": \"greenfield_pin_drop\", \"utm_campaign\": \"greenfield_link_click_campaign\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"e6bd0f15-cc64-4a20-a296-ecfa24be2192\"}|2023-04-26 04:06:58|
    |200074|e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f\"}|2023-04-26 04:05:02|
    |200075|e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"SPRING23\", \"clubID\": \"4755\", \"fbclid\": \"IwAR2CiLuh2rVrA7ThAcX-kNlbjF60Udu96P1vM69BagOILENuPguYIvfg61o_aem_AZsvlvCes7daZkuGZ0qTX6FXD0PwgQHmqRiv6OrNb2B9NP3FLLivz20UY-DSKbyLvWNl6CiMfEappv3zRLg9GedTqPlUGYJm4PO6Q5_AQwKnrHI1j-BPiDw5GzsdDXaDUY85se6hLujglGmKgdocf4QD\", \"hsa_ad\": \"23853502793350441\", \"hsa_acc\": \"2256012071346889\", \"hsa_cam\": \"23853324701250441\", \"hsa_grp\": \"23853324701230441\", \"hsa_net\": \"facebook\", \"hsa_src\": \"fb\", \"hsa_ver\": \"3\", \"utm_term\": \"Spring23_p1_c1_h1\", \"utm_medium\": \"paid_social\", \"utm_source\": \"facebook\", \"utm_content\": \"woodbury_pin_drop\", \"utm_campaign\": \"woodbury_link_click_campaign\"}, \"token\": \"e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f\"}|2023-04-26 04:05:02|
    |200076|e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:05:02\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"2601:447:555:f940:bc07:9573:cbc3:8f80\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f\", \"campaign\": \"woodbury_link_click_campaign\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"facebook\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"SPRING23\", \"clubID\": \"4755\", \"fbclid\": \"IwAR2CiLuh2rVrA7ThAcX-kNlbjF60Udu96P1vM69BagOILENuPguYIvfg61o_aem_AZsvlvCes7daZkuGZ0qTX6FXD0PwgQHmqRiv6OrNb2B9NP3FLLivz20UY-DSKbyLvWNl6CiMfEappv3zRLg9GedTqPlUGYJm4PO6Q5_AQwKnrHI1j-BPiDw5GzsdDXaDUY85se6hLujglGmKgdocf4QD\", \"hsa_ad\": \"23853502793350441\", \"hsa_acc\": \"2256012071346889\", \"hsa_cam\": \"23853324701250441\", \"hsa_grp\": \"23853324701230441\", \"hsa_net\": \"facebook\", \"hsa_src\": \"fb\", \"hsa_ver\": \"3\", \"utm_term\": \"Spring23_p1_c1_h1\", \"utm_medium\": \"paid_social\", \"utm_source\": \"facebook\", \"utm_content\": \"woodbury_pin_drop\", \"utm_campaign\": \"woodbury_link_click_campaign\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"e60dfcd4-8359-4f34-9b5a-a880ce0cd26f\"}|2023-04-26 04:05:02|
    |200073|cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8|4|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:04:59\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"35.555.103.5\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\", \"campaign\": \"Unknown/None\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"Enrollment Purchase\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7770\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\", \"aggregate-root-version\": 4}|2023-04-26 04:04:59|
    |200064|c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200065|c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7770\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\"}, \"token\": \"c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200066|c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:04:58\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"35.555.103.5\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c\", \"campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"programmatic\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7770\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"c8f2116a-1b14-4828-a655-0000f898249c\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200067|cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200068|cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7770\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\"}, \"token\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200069|cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:04:58\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"35.555.103.5\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\", \"campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"programmatic\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7770\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"cef11f85-695d-4e36-b1f4-bbf9cc27e0a8\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200070|fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200071|fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\UTMsTagged|{\"utm\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7770\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\"}, \"token\": \"fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200072|fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e|3|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:04:58\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"35.555.103.5\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e\", \"campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"programmatic\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"CRAZY8\", \"clubID\": \"7770\", \"utm_medium\": \"simplifi\", \"utm_source\": \"programmatic\", \"utm_campaign\": \"display_west_allis_geo_fencing\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"fb0de6d5-1267-4720-962b-e5e15bcc734e\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:58|
    |200062|5fce0d43-1f95-47c8-9c22-210a93dc04ef|1|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\SessionStarted|{\"token\": \"5fce0d43-1f95-47c8-9c22-210a93dc04ef\"}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"5fce0d43-1f95-47c8-9c22-210a93dc04ef\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:52|
    |200063|5fce0d43-1f95-47c8-9c22-210a93dc04ef|2|\\StorableEvents\\Utility\\Visitors\\ActivityLogged|{\"time\": \"2023-04-26 04:04:52\", \"activity\": {\"ip\": \"24.555.118.215\", \"route\": \"https://test.com/enroll\", \"token\": \"5fce0d43-1f95-47c8-9c22-210a93dc04ef\", \"campaign\": \"Unknown/None\", \"server_info\": [], \"activity_type\": \"Enrollment Purchase\", \"url_parameters\": {\"promo\": \"SPRING23\", \"clubID\": \"7701\"}}}|{\"aggregate-root-uuid\": \"5fce0d43-1f95-47c8-9c22-210a93dc04ef\"}|2023-04-26 04:04:52|
```

My working query is:

```
SELECT distinct replace(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PR.event_properties,'$.utm.utm_source')), ",", "")  as Utm, 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PR.event_properties,'$.utm.promo')) as Promo , 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip')) AS ip_address,
    L.*
FROM vapor.stored_events IP JOIN (SELECT vapor.stored_events.* FROM vapor.stored_events WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(event_properties,'$.utm.promo') IS NOT NULL) PR ON IP.aggregate_uuid = PR.aggregate_uuid
JOIN (SELECT * FROM leads) L ON L.ip_address = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip'))
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip') IS NOT NULL 
and  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip')) in (SELECT ip_address FROM leads)
ORDER BY IP.created_at DESC;
```

I'd like to get the stored_events.created_at column to show using the below(by adding **PR.created_at AS se_created_at,**), but when I do so it adds almost 1,000 more rows:

```
SELECT distinct replace(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PR.event_properties,'$.utm.utm_source')), ",", "")  as Utm, 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PR.event_properties,'$.utm.promo')) as Promo , 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip')) AS ip_address,
    PR.created_at AS se_created_at,
    L.*
FROM vapor.stored_events IP JOIN (SELECT vapor.stored_events.* FROM vapor.stored_events WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(event_properties,'$.utm.promo') IS NOT NULL) PR ON IP.aggregate_uuid = PR.aggregate_uuid
JOIN (SELECT * FROM leads) L ON L.ip_address = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip'))
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip') IS NOT NULL 
and  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(IP.event_properties,'$.activity.ip')) in (SELECT ip_address FROM leads)
ORDER BY IP.created_at DESC;
```

Any help on the would be GREATLY appreciated